# Do not create folder if already exists and return folder id

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api

I am using Google drive API. When first time my app run, user authenticate my app and after that I create a folder in root directory of the Google Drive lets say folder name is "My Folder". The app works fine until user disconnect the app from 'Google settings' app in Android. After disconnecting, the user again open the app and again authorise the app and again another folder with similar name "My Folder" gets created with different id. I do not want to create that folder again if it is exists and want to get it's id without requesting all the files in root folder and iterating the list

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode,
        final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
    case REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null
                && data.getExtras() != null) {
            String accountName = data
                    .getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
            if (accountName != null) {
                credential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
                service = getDriveService(credential);

                SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(
                        "pref", MODE_PRIVATE);
                preferences.edit().putString("accountName", accountName)
                        .commit();



            }
        }
        break;
    case REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION:
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {


                    File body = new File();
                    body.setTitle("My Folder");
                    body.setMimeType("application/vnd.google-apps.folder");

                    try {
                        File file = service.files().insert(body).execute();
                        String id = file.getId();

                        MyUtilities.saveInSharedPreference("drivefolderid",
                                id, ImportWizard.this);
                        Log.v("folder id ", "==>>" + id);
                    } catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(),
                                REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
                    } catch (IOException e) {

                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }).start();

        } else {
            startActivityForResult(credential.newChooseAccountIntent(),
                    REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
        }
        break;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to iterate all the user's files. I assume you are giving that folder a fixed name. If so use the search functionality of drive to find by name and type folder. its a single call with a single result. Hopefully the user didnt create another folder with the same name.